# Unable to navigate to website using Java Selenium ChromeDriver with ChromeOptions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Java Selenium's ChromeDriver to log in to my own google profile and navigate to a website. However, what I found out is that if I log in to my profile, I will not be able to navigate to any website. On the other hand, if I did not log in to my profile, I can navigate to the website.

I attach the code below for your reference, the code immediately below is able to log in to profile but unable to navigate to bing website.

```
package Package1;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Options;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // System Property for Chrome Driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

        String userProfile = "C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data";
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=" + userProfile);
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.get("https://bing.com");
    }
}
```

The code below is able to navigate to bing website, but for my usage I need it to have a profile.

```
package Package1;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Options;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // System Property for Chrome Driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe")

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://bing.com");
    }
}
```

I know I have imported some libraries that I did not use, that should not be the problem here. How should I edit my code to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved. If I have existing chrome browser opened then the code will not be able to log in to my profile and navigate to website. But if there are no instances of chrome browser opened prior to running the code. It will work.

Will appreciate it if anyone knows why this is the way?